# Sql self join along with non matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I have a table like so

```
id | user | name | action | created_at
--------------------------------------------------
1  | 42    | eve | open   | 2020-01-06 06:17:42
2  | 42    | eve | close  | 2020-01-06 06:27:42
3  | 42    | eve | open   | 2020-01-06 06:37:42
4  | 42    | eve | close  | 2020-01-06 06:47:42
5  | 42    | eve | open   | 2020-01-06 06:57:42
```

I need to get this table:

```
user | name | open | open_created_at     | close | close _created_at 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
42   | eve  | open | 2020-01-06 06:17:42 | close | 2020-01-06 06:27:42
42   | eve  | open | 2020-01-06 06:37:42 | close | 2020-01-06 06:47:42
42   | eve  | open | 2020-01-06 06:57:42 | null  | null
```

This is the table I am getting:

```
SELECT t1.user, t1.name, t1.action, t1.created_at, t2.action, t2.created_at 
FROM tabel t1, table t2
WHERE t1.user = t2.user AND t1.action = 'open' AND t2.action = 'close' AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at
GROUP BY t1.id


user | name | open | open_created_at     | close | close _created_at 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
42   | eve  | open | 2020-01-06 06:17:42 | close | 2020-01-06 06:27:42
42   | eve  | open | 2020-01-06 06:37:42 | close | 2020-01-06 06:47:42
```

How can i get a table with matching open/close in the same column along with the rows which has no matching close column?

Comment: mySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I'm guessing MySQL 5.6 since the query will get `GROUP BY` errors in MySQL 5.7+ or SQL Server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, and you need to move the `WHERE` clauses into the `JOIN` condition. You should also add aggregate functions around the `t2` values to ensure a consistent result:

```
SELECT t1.user, t1.name, t1.action AS open, t1.created_at AS open_created_at,
       MIN(t2.action) AS close, MIN(t2.created_at) AS close_created_at
FROM log t1
LEFT JOIN log t2 ON t1.user = t2.user AND t2.action = 'close' AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at
WHERE t1.action = 'open'
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.action, t1.created_at
```

Output:

```
user    name    open    open_created_at         close   close_created_at
42      eve     open    2020-01-06 06:17:42     close   2020-01-06 06:27:42
42      eve     open    2020-01-06 06:37:42     close   2020-01-06 06:47:42
42      eve     open    2020-01-06 06:57:42     (null)  (null)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3afd09d/5)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly but what is the use of MIN aggregate?

Comment: @Bhargav using `MIN(t2.created_at)` ensures that the `close_created_at` time is the earliest `close` time after the `open` time. In MySQL 5.7+ and most other SQL servers, any column that is not in the `GROUP BY` list is required to be aggregated, so using `MIN` on t2.action (which does nothing since all values are `close`) ensures this query will work if you upgrade your server.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to divide the process into 3 steps:

- Collect all rows that are `open` and sort them by `created_at` in ascending order. During this process, create a variable, say `@rank` to assign rank to each row in ascending order like 1,2,3 so on and so forth.
- Collect all rows that are `close` and sort them by `created_at` in ascending order. During this process, create a variable, say `@rank2` to assign rank to each row in ascending order like 1,2,3 so on and so forth.
- Now, do a `left join` on both tables based on `rank`.

**Query snippet:**

```
select d1.user,d1.name,d1.action as open,d1.open_created_at,d2.action as close,d2.close_created_at
from 
(
  select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,user,name,action,created_at as open_created_at
  from log,(select  @rank := 0) l1
  where action = 'open'
  order by created_at asc
) d1
left join
(
 select @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 as rank,user,name,action,created_at as close_created_at
  from log,(select  @rank2 := 0) l2
  where action = 'close'
  order by created_at asc

) d2
on d1.rank = d2.rank
```

**DB Fiddle:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYHyz45rtuiEXGQPbz3m6z/0